# Google Protocol Buffers checking if a field has been set

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am iterating over the fields of GPB message and have to find out the list of fields which have been set in the message

```
public void printFields(Person person){
Builder builder = person.toBuilder();
Descriptor descriptor = Person.getDescriptor();
List<FieldDescriptor> fields = descriptor.getFields();
for(FieldDescriptor fd : fields){
Object value = builder.get(fd); //this gives the value
// how to check if this field is set or not
}
}
```

Checking `value` for null doesnot help as there can be primitive types in the message as well.
I have read about hasXXX() methods on the message class which tells whether XXX has default value or explicit value, but how to invoke these using builder/descriptor/fieldDescriptor.

Comment: `person.hasField(fd)` or `builder.hasField(fd)`. See [javadoc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you can find the defined fields using the streaming api:

```
List<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor> definedPersonFields = Person.getDescriptor()
      .getFields()
      .stream()
      .filter(Person::hasField)
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is late, but may be useful for other people..

The below code will print modified attribute name and its value. you can change it identify populated attributes in proto

```
    Map<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, Object> modifiedFields = proto.getAllFields();

    for(Descriptors.FieldDescriptor fieldDescriptor : modifiedFields.keySet())
    {
        int protNum = fieldDescriptor.toProto().getNumber();
        Descriptors.FieldDescriptor.Type fieldType = fieldDescriptor.getType();
        Object value = modifiedFields.get(fieldDescriptor);

        System.out.println(fieldDescriptor.getFullName());
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need to use descriptor/fieldDescriptor? They are even not available if you define "option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME".
Anyway, you can do it already on a Person.Builder or just Person, e.g.:

```
   Builder builder = person.toBuilder();
   if (builder.hasXXX()){
          XXX xxx = builder.getXXX();
   }
```

Comment: that was the case with syntax version 2, the newest version is 3 where is no hasXXX() method present